# Como imprimir un array en un JtextField en Java Swing?

Tags: java, array, java-swing

Quiero imprimier una array que lo genere de la siguente forma

```
public String buscar(){
    numero = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    palabra = libreria[numero];
    return palabra;
}

public void cambiar(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < palabra.length() ; i++ ){
        aux [i] = "_";
    }
}
```

lo que quiero es cambiar la palabra por un "_" es para un juego de ahorcado pero al imprimirlo en un JTextField con `display.setText(aux.toString());`
[Ljava.lang.String;@

Comment: lo que quieres es que una palabras ejemplo hola se cambien por _ _ _ _

Comment: Si es precisamente lo que quiero

Comment: Y si usas list en vez de arrays normales que es menos coñazo?

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que quieres debes recorrer el array e ir concatenando cada elemento de este a una variable de tipo *String*, o mejor, utilizar un *StringBuilder* como te muestro a continuación.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0 ; i < palabra.length() ; i++ ){
    builder.append(aux[i]);
}
```

Ahora si puedes hacer algo como esto: `display.setText(builder.toString());`

Comment: Ya me lo imprime ahora solo que cuando presiono el boton que me ejecuta la funcion nuevamente, me agrega mas guiones en lugar de cambiar los por la nueva palabra.
Por ejemplo sin los guines doy click y sale "hola" y presiono de nuevo me cambia por otra palabra "perro" en cambio con los guiones solo agrega mas "----" en el segundo click serian los de la primera palabra mas la segunda "---------" y asi sigue agregando

Comment: Creo que eso ya es otro asunto. Te recomiendo que hagas otra pregunta explicando este particular y el problema que tienes.